# Twilio-Client always returns connection status as open on outbound call even if the recipient has not accepted the call yet

Tags: twilio

I am trying to get the status of outbound call made through `Twilio Client(js) v 1.10.1`. But the `.status()` method returns the value as "open" even if the call is in ringing state. I tried adding `enableRingingState: true` as a parameter while initializing the Twilio.Device and also set the `answerOnBridge="true"` while creating the TwiMl Dial verb at server side.

As per the official [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/connection#status), js sdk should be returning these status "pending", "connecting", "ringing", "open", "closed".

This is required to showing "calling..." until the call is picked and start the timer(mm:ss) in my dialer in browser as soon the call is picked.

**Note:** Tried the same with Twilio's Quickstart guide code as well.

/**** Pseudo Code is like below ***/
  // FRONT END CODE

```
let device = require('twilio-client').Device;
let outboundCall = '';
const twilioInit = () => {

    // axios call to get capability {token} from service

    device = device.setup(token,
                    {
                        allowIncomingWhileBusy: true,
                        enableRingingState: true
                    });

    device.ready(function () {
                    console.log("Twilio ready");                    
                    device.identity = "Ratan";  
                    console.log("Twilio Device ", device);
                });

    device.error(function (error) {
                    console.log("error in twilio ", error);
                    if (error.message == "JWT Token Expired") {
                        alert("token expired");
                    }
                    // If token has expired, dispatch an action to get new token.
                });

}

// on phone icon click i am calling the below method
const makeOutboundCall = () => {
    outboundCall = device.connect({        
        To: '+911234567890' // This is not the real phone number, I use number from list of Twilio verified numbers
      });

    outboundCall.on('ringing', function (hasEarlyMedia) {
        console.log("ringing");
      });

    // Then tracking the status of this outboundCall object in setInterval function with a interval of one second by outboundCall.status() and clearing the.. 
    // ..setInterval once the call disconnects

}
```

// BACK END CODE - SERVER SIDE (WEBHOOK)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/callCustomers", produces= "text/xml")
public String callByBrowserToMobile(@RequestParam String ApplicationSid, @RequestParam String ApiVersion, 
                                        @RequestParam String Called, @RequestParam String Caller, 
                                        @RequestParam String CallStatus, @RequestParam String To,
                                        @RequestParam String From, @RequestParam String CallSid,
                                        @RequestParam String Direction, @RequestParam String AccountSid) {

      Number number = new Number.Builder(To).build();
      Dial dial = new Dial.Builder().answerOnBridge(true).number(number).callerId(myTwilioNumber).build();
      VoiceResponse response = new VoiceResponse.Builder().dial(dial).build();
      logger.info(response.toXml());              
      return response.toXml();    
}
```

The call is placed correctly but the issue is only with tracking outbound call status with twilio js library so that i can start call timer in UI once the call is picked by recipient.

Comment: It would be great if someone can help me out here. I was expecting philnash Twilio Developer Evangelist to answer my query.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to setup the Twilio Device and listen for the event changes?

Comment: I have added the Psuedo code. Please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

**Edit: Found out what the issue was**

When using `<Dial answerOnBridge="true">` to make the ringing events available, the `<Dial>` needs to be the first TwiML that Twilio sees when it starts the call. When you are using a free trial account Twilio plays a message at the start of the call which acts as the first TwiML that is seen, so the `answerOnBridge` attribute doesn't take effect and you don't get the ringing events as you'd expect.

To fix this particular issue you will need to upgrade your account so that Twilio no longer reads out the trial account message at the start of the call.

**Original answer:**

I wouldn't use `setInterval` to poll the status of the call. Instead, I would listen to the events on the connection object. So your `makeOutboundCall` function should look a bit like this:

```js
const makeOutboundCall = () => {
    outboundCall = device.connect({        
        To: TO_NUMBER
    });

    outboundCall.on("ringing", (hasEarlyMedia) => {
        console.log("The call has started and the other phone is ringing.");
    });

    outboundCall.on("accept", (connection) => {
        console.log("The other person answered the phone!");
    });

    outboundCall.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log("The other person hung up.");
    });
}
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: I tried your suggested approach but it didn't help. Even though the call was ringing at recipient's phone(not answered yet), it already printed "The call has started and the other phone is ringing." and "The other person answered the phone!" in console. You may try same with Twilio's quickstart guide code(https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/client-quickstart-js)

Comment: @RatanDeep I'm not sure what's going on for you. I just cloned that quickstart, followed the instructions to set up the Twilio Functions I needed, plugged them into my TwiML app and then made a call to myself and [I got the 'ringing' event as the call started, and the 'connect' event as the call was answered](https://monosnap.com/direct/PGdxi8vopwJIyCm5YjFWT0gzv30cah). I didn't change anything and it worked in the way you are asking for. What are you finding?

Comment: @Philansh, thank you for trying that out. In my case, I am not using twilio functions, instead I have the webhook methods created on my server and configured the same in Twilio Programmable Voice my TwiML app. Let me try that using Twilio functions and share the findings. Do you think my server code for creating TwiML(posted in the question) is fine or does it need any modifications?

Comment: Can you share your latest code for the `makeOutboundCall` function? Did you try the code I shared?

Comment: I added that as an answer below.

Comment: Hi @philnash, thanks for your guidance, it worked fine with upgraded account.